# Jupyter does not show folder in my working directory

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am running docker Jupiter notebook on a MacBook Pro. When starting Jupyter  home only shows some of the folders in the working directory.  When I cd to a folder and use it as the working directory I get the message "Notebook list is empty."
See examples below.

My directory:

```
LewIss-MacBook-Pro:MyTensorFlow lewleib$ ls
```

Gorner_tensorflow-mnist     Tensor2018          models
Gorner_tensorflow-rnn       Untitled.ipynb          tensorflow
MyDeepTest          generate_hmb3.py        tensorflow-without-a-phd-master
My_tensor1.html         guided              testgen
NeuralNet1.ipynb        install.sh
README.md           mnist

One level down:

LewIss-MacBook-Pro:MyDeepTest lewleib$ ls
README.md       guided          models
generate_hmb3.py    install.sh      testgen

And one level more:

```
LewIss-MacBook-Pro:guided lewleib$ ls
```

chauffeur_guided.py epoch_guided.py     ncoverage.py        rambo_guided.py

When I try and call Jupiter note book:

```
LewIss-MacBook-Pro:guided lewleib$ docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -v ~/lewleib/MyTensorFlow/MyDeepTest/guided:/notebooks tensorflow/tensorflow
```

I get the following:

> guided
>   Last Modified Name 
>   ..seconds ago
>   The notebook list is empty.

Comment: Any suggestions @Y. Luo

Comment: Any suggestions  @programmerq

Comment: Any suggestions , @Engineero

Comment: Any suggestions @Coeur ?

Answer (score 0):

It ran with the following:

```
LewIss-MacBook-Pro:guided lewleib$ docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -v /Users/lewleib/MyTensorFlow/guided:/notebooks tensorflow/tensorflow
```